# C++ DirectX Trouble toggling a function with mouse click

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm making a GUI for a simple game and I want when I click in a box once It will draw a X into the box like this:

[image: X]

```
bool ToggleX = false;
if (P.y >= xCenterY - 147 && P.y >= xCenterY - 134 
    && P.x >= xCenterX - 311 && P.x <= xCenterX - 298 &&
    GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 1)
{
    ToggleX = !ToggleX;
}
```

My "function" to draw the X:

```
if (ToggleX)
{
    Draw->String(xCenterX - 308, xCenterY - 148, 
                 D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 255, 255), D3Vars::sFont, "X");
}
```

But the problem is that if I click somewhere outside the box and I move the cursor over the box it gets "ticked" even if I did not click inside the box.

Also if I move my cursor out of the box after I clicked the X dissapears and when I move the cursor back over the box it reappers like this:

[image: Gif]

What should I do?

([Full Code](http://pastebin.com/c1wsJGn1))

**Soulution:**

```
if (P.y >= xCenterY - 147 && P.y <= xCenterY - 134 && P.x >= xCenterX - 311 && P.x <= xCenterX - 298 && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 1)
{
    ToggleX = !ToggleX;
}
```

Comment: You have two `>=` tests for `P.y`, presumably one of them should be `<=` instead.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Ah thank you! Did not see that but I still have the same problem as before.

Comment: I doubt you have the same problem as before. Perhaps you have another problem.

Comment: @JonathanPotter No the problem is still that if I click inside the box the X appears but when I move my mouse out of the box the X dissapears. I want the X or my function to run even if i move my cursor out of the box.

Comment: Then you need to set a flag when the button is clicked inside the box, and display the X for as long as that flag is set. The computer's only doing what you tell it to do.

Comment: You haven't posted enough code for anyone to be able to answer.  How is this code called?  Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MilesBudnek I added a pastebin link to the source where I run the code. And I will start workin on the MCVE!

Comment: @MilesBudnek Thanks for the help I managed to get it fixed!